# java phone book array how to add new information and display old info

Tags: java

hi i am tring to do make a phone book this is what i got so far, any help would be apperciated. the entries should be sorted by last name and every contact has to maintain in alphabetical order. and after every new entry the old entries should be displayed

```
package book;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Contact[] contacts = new Contact[20];

       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

         for (int i = 0 ; i < contacts.length; i++) {
         }
    }
```

Class:

```
package book;

public class Contact {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String phone, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }




}
```

Comment: is this a homework assignment ?

Comment: Hi attash! Could you add some code about what you have tried for sorting in alphabetical order, or a more specific question about it? Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941422/how-to-sort-array-in-alphabetical-order-without-using-array-sortjava might help with the sorting part

Answer (score 1):

```
package main.test;

public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String phone, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Contact obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.lastName.compareTo(obj.lastName);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", phone=" + phone + ", email=" + email
                + "]";
    }


}
```

====Main class ==

```
public class MainContact {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Contact> lsCont = new ArrayList<Contact>();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String firstName;
            String lastName;
            String phone;
            String email;
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                System.out.println("insert firstname : ");
                firstName = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("insert lastName : ");
                lastName = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("insert phone : ");
                phone = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("insert email : ");
                email = scanner.nextLine();
                Contact cont = new Contact(firstName, lastName, phone, email);
                lsCont.add(cont);
                Collections.sort(lsCont);
                for (Contact contact : lsCont) {
                    System.out.println(contact.toString());
                }   
            }       

        }
    }
```

Comment: is there any way of not using an array list at all?